# Generate a list from another list with comma separated values

Tags: python, list

I have list as :

```
mylist = ['7','8,9','10', '11,12']
```

I want a list as :

```
['7','8','9','10','11','12']
```

Closest i was able to get was using this code :

```
mylist = ['7','8,9','10', '11,12']
ab = []
for e in mylist:
    if ',' in e:
       ab.append(e.split(','))
mylist2 = [x for x in mylist  if ',' not in x]
print mylist2 #clean list

merged = []
for f in ab:
     merged =  mylist2 + f
```

But, this omits the '8','9' sequence, how can i easily achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your existing code is pretty simple:

```
merged = []
for f in ab:
     merged =  mylist2 + f
```

For each `f` in `ab`, you forget whatever was in `merged` and replace it with `mylist + f`. So, at the end, only the last `f` ends up in `merged`.

You probably wanted something like this:

```
for f in ab:
    mylist2 = mylist2 + f
merged = mylist2
```

This way we keep adding each `f` onto the list and storing the result back in the same place.

---

However, there's a much simpler way to solve this. Instead of pulling out the ones with commas and then adding them back in, just handle everything as it comes:

```
mylist = ['7','8,9','10', '11,12']
merged = []
for element in mylist:
    elements = element.split(',')
    merged += elements
```

This keeps everything, and keeps it all in the original order, and it's a lot simpler. (Notice that `'7'.split(',')` is perfectly fine—it returns a single-element list `['7']`, which you can add onto the accumulated list the same way as `['8', '9']`.)

You can make this more concise by first using a comprehension to split each element, then merging and flattening the result. There are a few ways to write this, but here's a couple:

```
merged = [subelement for element in mylist for subelement in element.split(',')]

from itertools import chain
merged = list(chain.from_iterable(element.split(',') for element in mylist))
```

Comment: Yup that solves the problem, but is there a one-liner in python to solve such problem rather than doing like two For-loops?

Comment: @PetPan See the edit for two one-liners, but I think the explicit loop over `+=` is probably easier for a novice to understand.

Comment: On your third code snippet, you can replace the 2-lines inside the `for` loop with `merged.extend(element.split(','))`. nice answer however!

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes, or `merged += element.split(',')`. But I thought being clear and understandable to a novice was more important than being concise. If you want concise, use the comprehension.

Comment: I like the fact that i am treated as novice, because then only i get to see how easily something can be achieved, People put their pride when someone uses such sentences but i liked your answer anyways. Save for Ev.Kounis :)

Comment: @PetPan We're all novices in at least 95% of what's on Stack Overflow. If I'm asking for an answer in a language I've barely started using, I usually want an explanation that I can understand before getting to the part about how to shave off 1.3ns or 6 characters. So I try to answer that way for other people.

Comment: You could probably even simplify this more perhaps by `mylist = [x.split(',') for x in mylist]` then chain it `list(itertools.chain(*mylist))`.

Comment: @l'L'l That’s equivalent to the last version (except I used `chain.from_iterable(…)` instead of `chain(*…)`, which doesn’t really matter for something as small as `mylist`…).

Comment: Indeed, I think with `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` it doesn't require unpacking either if I remember correctly. Nice explanation and examples shown in your answer :) +1

Comment: @l'L'l Right, and avoiding unpacking keeps it lazy all the way up to the final `list` construction. Which doesn’t matter here, since we’re just chaining four lists together, but I guess subconsciously I did it on principle: once you bring in itertools and genexprs, might as well go all the way. (Although I didn’t bring in an `isplit` iterator…)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list-comprehension for that:

```
mylist = ['7','8,9','10', '11,12']
merged = [n for sublist in [packet.split(',') for packet in mylist] for n in sublist]
print(merged)   # -> ['7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
```

This capitalizes on the fact that `'7'.split(',')` returns `['7']` instead of, say, raising an error. As a result, we can use `split()` on all entries and finally *flatten* the nested structure we create.

---

EDIT:

As @abarnet points out, the above list-comprehension can be made simpler and faster if rewritten as:

```
merged = [n for packet in mylist for n in packet.split()]
```

Comment: You don't need the inner nested comprehension here. Just `[n for m in mylist for n in m.split(',')]` will do the same thing, without an extra layer of looping, and without creating a temporary list of splits. And I think the only reason that isn't obvious is those names `n`, `m`, and `x` don't make it clear what each piece is; if you name them `subelement`, `element`, and `splitelement` or `element`, `sublist`, `split` or something, you'd see that you don't need the list of sublists.

Comment: @abarnert To be honest, I think I have never seen a list-comprehension like that before. I noticed it in your answer too. very nice!! I will however leave that one for your answer.

Comment: Your new names are clearer than mine. I also like your explanation of why it's safe to split all the strings better than mine. So, definitely worth having both answers here.

Comment: Yup i selected both as good answers, thanks to you both. Much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

try also this;

```
import numpy as np
merged = list(np.concatenate([i.split(',') for i in mylist]))
```

Comment: While this will work, why would you bring in numpy for something that isn't going to benefit from it? And why loop over `i in range(len(mylist))` when you're only going to use `mylist[i]` instead of just looping over `mylist`?